# Get an Array from Reduce Method

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Is it possible to make an array from my reduce result?

For Example this code

```js
const fruitBasket = ['banana', 'cherry', 'orange', 'apple', 'cherry', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'orange', 'fig'];

const count = fruitBasket.reduce((tally, fruit) => {
  tally[fruit] = (tally[fruit] || 0) + 1;
  return tally;
}, {})

console.log(count) // { banana: 2, cherry: 3, orange: 3, apple: 2, fig: 1 }
```

Can I get an array from *count*?

Something like

````
const NewArrayName = [
 {fruit: "banana", num: "2"},
 {fruit: "orange", num: "3"}
 ]; ```
````

Comment: `{"orange" : "2", "banana" : "3"}` is not an array

Comment: Object or Array ?

Comment: `["orange" : "2", "banana" : "3"]` is not a valid syntax. Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an object with a key `values` in `reduce` method and then use `Object.values()` to get desired result:

```js
const fruitBasket = ['banana', 'cherry', 'orange', 'apple', 'cherry', 'orange', 
    'apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'orange', 'fig'];

const count = fruitBasket.reduce((acc, fruit) => {
  acc.values[fruit] = (acc.values[fruit] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {values: {}})

const output = Object.values(count)
console.log(`An array: `, output) 
console.log(`An object: `, ...output)
```

UPDATE:

To get "banana" and "2":

```
let banana = output[0]['banana'];
```

Comment: Thanks, but can I from that Array, for example somehow just get out "banana" and "2".?
So I can style each fruit on a html page, and the number aswell.

Answer (score 0):

change your initial value from an obj to an array and it will be an array. Then you can get the count by tally. `${"fruit name here"}` by calling it on the count as a callback maybe.

```
const fruitBasket = ['banana', 'cherry', 'orange', 'apple', 'cherry', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'orange', 'fig'];

const count = fruitBasket.reduce((tally, fruit) => {
  tally[fruit] = (tally[fruit] || 0) + 1;
  return tally;
}, [])

console.log(count) // [ banana: 2, cherry: 3, orange: 3, apple: 2, fig: 1 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can get your desired output in an array of objects-

```js
const fruitBasket = ['fig', 'banana', 'cherry', 'orange', 'apple', 'cherry', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'orange', 'fig', 'pineapple'];




const fruitObj = fruitBasket.reduce((acc, fruit) => {


  if (!acc.length) {

    acc.push({ 'fruit': fruit, 'count': 1 });

  } else {


    let i = 0;

    while (i < acc.length) {

      if (acc[i]['fruit'] !== fruit && i === acc.length - 1) {
        acc.push({ 'fruit': fruit, 'count': 1 });
        break;

      } else if (acc[i]['fruit'] === fruit) {
        ++acc[i]['count'];
        break;
      }
      i++;

    }
  }
  return acc;

}, []);

console.log(fruitObj);
```